# Separate Dockerrun.aws.json per environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For a project, I have two environments in AWS Elastic Beanstalk: acceptance and production. Acceptance uses a simple t2.nano instance, while production uses a t2.medium.

The t2.nano has 500 MB of RAM, while the t2.medium has 4 GB. Therefore I want to have different memory allocations in my Dockerrun.aws.json depending on the environment I'm deploying to. This doesn't seem to be possible.

What I've tried:

1. Setup two Dockerrun.aws.json files: `Dockerrun.aws.json.acceptance` and `Dockerrun.aws.json.production`.
2. In an `.ebextensions` script, adjust the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01unzip.sh` script (with `sed`) so that it copies the correct `Dockerrun.aws.json.[env]` file to `Dockerrun.aws.json`, after unzipping the source and before it loops through container definitions.

This works partly:

- The `Dockerrun.aws.json` file is indeed replaced with the environment-specific one.
- However, the definitions are processed already before the entire source is even unzipped: I had a fallback `Dockerrun.aws.json` file in my source root, and apparently that one is used. When I delete that file, `eb deploy` fails with `No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment`

What I could do:

- Do not use `eb deploy` but a custom deploy script, which first replaces the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file with the environment-specific one, then runs `eb deploy`

But if there's an option to stick to pure EB CLI instead of using custom scripts, that would have my preference.

The main goal of having two Dockerrun's is to have different memory allocations per container, and to load a custom PHP-FPM config per environment (by mounting an environment-specific directory with config files to `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d`), which have different settings for child processes.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but anyone looking to deploy different `Dockerrun.aws.json` files to different environments may find this helpful.

As OP has already discovered, definitions need to defined at deployment. Attempting to use .ebextensions is too late in the lifecycle.

The `what I could do` from OP - using a custom script to deploy is exactly what we do.

Specifically, we have our CI run commands which:

1. Replace image tag inside the container definition.
2. Copy `.ebextensions/` and `Dockerrun.aws.worker.json => Dockerrun.aws.json` to a separate folder.
3. That separate folder (total 4 files) is zipped.
4. Finally deployed using `eb deploy`.